# How to return both fun and jac in scipy.optimize.least_squares

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, scipy-optimize

I am using `scipy.optimize.least_squares` to minimise a function of >40 parameters and for my particular problem I can express the jacobian of my function analytically. However, the function I minimize and the jacobian share a lot of the same calculations. Is there a way to return both `fun` and `jac` from a single function? I know this can be done when using `scipy.optimize.minimize` but haven't figured out a way to do it with `scipy.optimize.least_squares`.

Comment: Related question with food answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72768031/2629879

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct analog of `fun_and_jac`, it seems.
A workaround is to refactor a common part of a calculation and use it in both callables. For instance (here's a deliberately simplied example):

```
In [8]: class F(object):
   ...:     def fun(self, x):
   ...:         return fun_rosenbrock(x)
   ...:     def jac(self, x):
   ...:         return jac_rosenbrock(x)
   ...:     

In [9]: x0_rosenbrock = np.array([2, 2])
   ...: f = F()
   ...: res_3 = least_squares(f.fun, x0_rosenbrock, f.jac)
   ...: res_3.x, res_3.cost
   ...: 
   ...: 
Out[9]: (array([1., 1.]), 0.0)
```

Here `*_rosenbrock` are taken from the [docstring example of `least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html):

```
def fun_rosenbrock(x):
     return np.array([10 * (x[1] - x[0]**2), (1 - x[0])])

def jac_rosenbrock(x):
    return np.array([
        [-20 * x[0], 10],
        [-1, 0]])
```