# Solving nonlinear least-squares with function returning both value and jacobian

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to speed up the solving of a nonlinear least-squares problem in Python. I can compute both the function value and the Jacobian via one forwardpass, `(val, jac) = fun`. A solver like [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy-optimize-least-squares) only accepts two seperate functions, `fun` and `jac`, which for my problem means that the function value has to be computed twice per iteration (once in `fun`, and once in `jac`).

Is there a trick, for avoiding solving the primal problem twice?

The more general function `scipy.optimize.minimize` support the above style with the `jac=True` keyword, but it's slow for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to use the [MemoizeJac](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/85895a2fdfed853801846b56c9f1418886e2ccc2/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py#L57) decorator. This is exactly what is done under the hood of `scipy.optimize.minimize` for `jac=True`:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from scipy.optimize._optimize import MemoizeJac

def fun_and_jac(x):
    return x**2 - 5 * x + 3, 2 * x - 5

fun = MemoizeJac(fun_and_jac)
jac = fun.derivative

res = least_squares(fun, x0=0, jac=jac)
print(res)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. But I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.optimize._optimize'` on Scipy 1.8.1. Of course, I could copy paste the code.

Comment: @fhchl Works without any problems for me on scipy 1.8.1. It's definitely there as you can see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance/1.8.x/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py). Still not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: My bad, was in the wrong environment when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a bit of a hack:

```py
val_cache = {}
jac_cache = {}

def val_fun(*args):
    try:
        return val_cache.pop(args)
    except KeyError:
        (val, jac) = fun(*args)
        jac_cache[args] = jac
        return val

def jac_fun(*args):
    try:
        return jac_cache.pop(args)
    except KeyError:
        (val, jac) = fun(*args)
        val_cache[args] = val
        return jac
```

Comment: Love the caching idea, but args is a numpy array and unhashable.

Comment: @fhchl Does it work when caching on `id(arr)` instead of `args`? It should if it passes in the same array for both. Need to be careful to not call `id` on a temporary tuple containing the arguments though.

Comment: It does work for `method=trf` but for the other two methods, sometimes the jacobian cache misses or something is mixed up with the ids that leads to poor results. Using `tuple(arr)` as the cache key and combining the cache for both value and jacobian by storing the tuple `(val, jac)` seems to give few cache misses and the correct results for all thre methods (`trf`, `dogbox` and `lm`). Yey!

Comment: And replacing `pop` by dictionary lookup (e.g. `cache[tuple(arr)]`) removes all cache misses.

Comment: @fhchl I assumed each value would only be used once. You might want to look into some fixed-size caches then to prevent running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

> If jac is a Boolean and is True, fun is assumed to return a tuple (f, g) containing the objective function and the gradient.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html?highlight=minimize

So you can simply do it like this:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def function(x):
    '''Function that returns both fun and jac'''
    return x**2 - 5 * x + 3, 2 * x - 5

print(minimize(function, 0, jac=True))
```

Edit, reread your question, it seems this option also works for `least_squares` but is undocumented.

This works as well:

```py
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def function(x):
    '''Function that returns both fun and jac'''
    return x**2 - 5 * x + 3, 2 * x - 5

print(least_squares(function, 0, jac=True))
```

Comment: I am getting `ValueError: "jac" must be '2-point', '3-point', 'cs' or callable` with scipy 1.8.1